MedusaJS does not trigger subscribers. Why?
I wrote a subscriber to send messages when placing an order, but it is not triggered. I removed all the code from my email client and left only the logs, but it still doesn't work.
event-bus-redis works, new events are created in my redis.
import {
    Logger,
    OrderService,
    SubscriberArgs,
    SubscriberConfig,
} from "@medusajs/medusa";

type OrderPlacedEvent = {
    id: string;
    no_notification: boolean;
};

export default async function orderPlacedHandler({data, eventName, container}: SubscriberArgs<OrderPlacedEvent>) {

    const logger = container.resolve<Logger>("logger")

    console.log("Order placed event received")
    console.log(data)
    console.log(eventName)

    logger.log("Order placed event received")


    const orderService: OrderService = container.resolve('orderService');

    const order = await orderService.retrieve(data.id, {
        relations: ["items", "items.variant", "items.variant.product"],
    });

    // Do something with the order
}

export const config: SubscriberConfig = {
    event: OrderService.Events.PLACED,
    context: {
        subscriberId: "order-place-handler",
    },

};

